# taking timestamp from resultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to execute the SQL query using java like

```
Statement st = UserDBConn.createStatement();                                                                
ResultSet dummy = st.executeQuery("select unix_timestamp('2012-03-07 00:00:00')");
```

How to take the timeStamp value from this resultSet. please correct me if am doing anything wrong.

**Note : I tried the same query in mysql, it gives 1331058600**.

Thanks. I tried

```
**ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("select unix_timestamp('2012-03-07 00:00:00') as theTime");
Timestamp time = result.getTimestamp("theTime");**
```

It throws "**Before start of result set**". What may be the error.

Exception is as below

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:3628) at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1767) at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestampInternal(ResultSet.java:3792) at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:1905) at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:1919) at DBCount.main(DBCount.java:31)
```

Comment: what error you get?? Is **Before start of result set** is ERROR??? What output you are expecting??

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:3628)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1767)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestampInternal(ResultSet.java:3792)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:1905)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:1919)
 at DBCount.main(DBCount.java:31)

Comment: see my updated answer... the problem is that you are not pointing the first record to read...

Comment: is problem solved or still persist...

Answer (score 2):

Hope below is what you want...

```
while (dummy.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

### Update 1

Change your query to below.

```
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("select unix_timestamp('2012-03-07 00:00:00') as theTime");
result.next();
Timestamp time = result.getTimestamp("theTime");
```

You will get what you want...

Answer (score 1):

If all you're asking is how to get the timestamp from the resultset you use the getTimestamp method of the resulset. You may be able to use, "unix_timestamp" as the column label but if not change your query to something like st.executeQuery("select unix_timestamp('2012-03-07 00:00:00') as theTime"); and use "theTime" as the column label

```
dummy.getTimestamp("columnLabel");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: Set an alias to my select and use `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` method to retrieve the timestamp.

```
Statement st = UserDBConn.createStatement();                                                                
ResultSet dummy = st.executeQuery("select unix_timestamp('2012-03-07 00:00:00') as ts");
while (dummy.hasNext()) {
    Timestamp ts = dummy.getTimestamp("ts");
}
```

Comment: I think your last line should be `Timestamp ts = dummy.getTimestamp("ts");` as you are saying as `as timestamp` **OR** your `as timestamp` should be `as ts`...

Comment: But i gave columnName as 'theTime' in my query

Comment: @vignesh, change `ts` to `myTime` then....